# Am I using 'the' too much in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, articles, american-english, british-english

> When the request to the web server succeeds, we need to redirect the
>   user to the top of the service page.

I'm not sure when I can omit preposition such as 'a', 'an', 'the', so I just add these preposition whenever I use nouns.

- I didn't add 'the' in front of 'nouns' in the sentence above just because I feel it sounds right to me...

Added, from OP's comment: The reason why I chose to use the zero article before "nouns" in my sentence is because I know I can omit 'the' when I'm not talking about a specific thing. For example, we can say like 'Dogs are cute' when we talk about something in general. So, I didn't use 'the' before nouns in my sentence. But... now I'm not sure. Would it be wrong if I had used 'the' in front of 'nouns' in my sentence? In that sentence in my question, I was talking about the five 'nouns' in my sentence which I didn't add 'the' in front of them. So, I feel like I should've used 'the' in front of them.

Comment: All your instances of *the* there are perfectly fine, and indeed mandatory. I'm going to send your question over to our sister-site for [ell.se] where you may get answers better suited to your needs.

Comment: Fortunately, your feeling is reliable here. Can you tell us _why_ you chose to use the zero article before _nouns_, or was the decision based only upon your feeling? Unfortunately, your feelings about prepositions are _not_ reliable.. _"A, an"_ and _"the"_ are not prepositions. Do you know what an _article_ is in English?

Comment: @tchrist Thank you for leading me to ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The reason why I chose to use the zero article before "nouns" in my sentence is because I know I can omit 'the' when I'm not talking about a specific thing. For example, we can say like 'Dogs are cute' when we talk about something in general. So, I didn't use 'the' before nouns in my sentence. But... now I'm not sure. Would it be wrong if I had used 'the' in front of 'nouns' in my sentence? In that sentence in my question, I was talking about the five 'nouns' in my sentence which I didn't add 'the' in front of them. So, I feel like I should've used 'the' in front of them.

Comment: Your reasoning is good. It would not be good English to use **the** before _nouns_ in your sentence. However, it _would_ also be good English to say _"..whenever I use **a noun**."_ Can you see why that is so?  (It is important for you to understand that **a**, **an**, and **the** are not prepositions, too.)

Comment: "..whenever I use a noun." sounds right. Is it okay to say "...whenever I use nouns"? Does it convey the same meaning as the first one? Today, I was writing a document in English and in that document, I wrote a sentence 'registered users can do blah blah blah". But, when I wrote that sentence, I wonder if it's more appropriate to write "a registered user can do blah blah blah".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change nothing. As a native English speaker, I will tell you that there is no sense of overuse of the word *the* in your example sentence.

The word *the* (also *a*, *an*) is actually considered an *article* and not a *preposition*. It is quite essential to precede many nouns with such an article as you have done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Oh yes, it meant an article not a preposition ;) I made a mistake!